# iPhone MapKit: Annotation images get reset back to pins

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkmapview, mkpinannotationview

I'm adding several annotations to a MapView and using a custom image instead of the default pins. I am using the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method to set the custom image like this:

```
view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placemark.png"];
```

And I've also tried:

```
[(MKPinAnnotationView *)view setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placemark.png"]];
```

Now, these both set the image just fine. But when an annotation is either tapped or the `mapType` changes to Satellite or Hybrid, it resets back to the red pin image.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 18):

Don't use MKPinAnnotationView - just use MKAnnotationView.

Answer (score 3):

I think I got it. I ended up having to subclass MKAnnotationView.

Answer (score 0):

```
MKAnnotationView* pinView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];

pinView.animatesDrop=YES;
pinView.canShowCallout=YES;
pinView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"userMain.png"];
```

Don't give `MKPinAnnotation` its takes default pin annotation. Use only `MKAnnotationView` object and don't use:

```
pinView.animatesDrop=YES;
```

Comment: I think the edit was to conform to the standard that differentiates code from narrative. Notice how your code is in Courier font, and your narrative isn't.