# MKMapView Pins Refreshing Color on Click

Tags: iphone, objective-c, annotations

I have several custom MKPinAnnotationView on my map with different images(colored pins).  Everything works fine until I either click on a pin or change the map to a different view(satellite/road)... when I do either of these, my pins will revert back to the classic red color.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please refer to this answer for a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087738/iphone-mapkit-annotation-images-get-reset-back-to-pins/2089971#2089971