# xcode how to refresh MapView with custom annotations?

Tags: xcode, ios7, dictionary, annotations, custom-view

I am using MapView with Custom Annotations.
I let user change map view type and once it is changed then all the annotations are looking as default (red).

Is there anything special I need to do to keep my annotations with custom view?
How can I get custom view back?

```
-(void)changeMapType:(id)sender
{
    switch (((UISegmentedControl *)sender).selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            map.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
            break;
        case 1:
            map.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
            break;
        case 2:
            map.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
            break;

        default:
            map.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087738/iphone-mapkit-annotation-images-get-reset-back-to-pins - glad it exists.

Comment: The ticket can be closed.